# redux-persist: What's the difference between persist and rehydrate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

When should you persist and when should you rehydrate? The naming convention is very confusing as the author barely mentions what they mean in the context of [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

Comment: Persisting state is when you are saving redux state into some sort of storage e. g. local storage in a browser or AsyncStorage when your application runs on the Android or IOS phone. Rehidrating is when redux state is  initialized with data stored in a storage. Redux state usually has to be rehidretaed upon application start and is persisted after being changed.

Answer (score 5):

Without really knowing the library:

persist = writing the store to any kind of storage that survives closing your browser session.

rehydrate = reading from that storage and putting the data back into the javascript runtime, so redux can access it.

At least this is what they *should* mean, if not I'd recommend to ditch that library for being confusing ;)